# Package requirements openglucose

Tags: package-management

I am trying to install openglucose (https://blogs.gnome.org/xclaesse/2014/09/08/openglucose-again/#comments) on my ubuntu machine. But I have issues with some dependencies. I don't know how to install the requested packages bellow. Can some give some advice how to do this? Thank you very much for your help.

> configure: error: Package requirements (   glib-2.0 >= 2.40.0
>   gobject-2.0 >= 2.40.0   gio-2.0 >= 2.40.0   gusb >= 0.1.6   gtk+-3.0
>
> > = 3.10   webkit2gtk-3.0 >= WEBKIT_REQUIRED ) were not met:
>
> No package 'gusb' found No package 'gtk+-3.0' found No package
>   'webkit2gtk-3.0' found
>
> Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
>   installed software in a non-standard prefix.
>
> Alternatively, you may set the environment variables
>   OPENGLUCOSE_CFLAGS and OPENGLUCOSE_LIBS to avoid the need to call
>   pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the necessary development files, you need to install `libgusb-dev`, `libgtk-3-dev`, and `libwebkit2gtk-3.0-dev`. Running `sudo apt-get install libgusb-dev libgtk-3-dev libwebkit2gtk-3.0-dev` will install the necessary packages for you.